# SSRS Authentication

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have several links in my SSRS report which redirect to another report on another SSRS server. I need user credentials to be stored somehow when I click on this link. As of now, when I get redirected to another report on the other server, I have to enter in the user credentials again.

Is there a way to make it so I do not have to enter them in again?

Comment: What happens if you just go straight to the linked URL? Does it ask for credentials? That's not normal

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do what you are asking. However. If you were to modify your reports to use Windows Integrated Security it would achieve the same result. This way you can allow people access to certain reports without ever having to put in credentials for ANY report.

This solution is assuming the User accounts all have access on the other Report Server as well.